# Appending string to null values in output file with awk

Tags: awk, merge, null

I am merging file1:

```
ID_0001 0001 0 0 1 -9
ID_0002 0002 0 0 1 -9
ID_0003 0003 0 0 1 -9
ID_0004 0004 0 0 1 -9
```

and file2:

```
ID_0001 0001 1.25
ID_0002 0002 3.09
ID_0004 0004 2.69
```

based on a common value in column 1 of each input file, with the following awk command:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {h[$1] = $3; next} {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,h[$1]}' file2 file1 > file3
```

The resulting output file (file3) looks like this:

```
 ID_0001 0001 0 0 1 1.25
 ID_0002 0002 0 0 1 3.09
 ID_0003 0003 0 0 1 
 ID_0004 0004 0 0 1 2.69
```

How do I change the script to either retain the "-9" from file1 (when there is no column 1 match with file2), or (alternatively) replace null values in column 6 of the output file with "-9" (note: retaining the column 6 value from file1 is preferred (i.e. option 1):

Desired output:

```
 ID_0001 0001 0 0 1 1.25
 ID_0002 0002 0 0 1 3.09
 ID_0003 0003 0 0 1 -9
 ID_0004 0004 0 0 1 2.69
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done using ternary conditional operator in the syntax `condition?true_actions:false_actions` like this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {h[$1] = $3; next} {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$1 in h?h[$1]:$6}' file2 file1
ID_0001 0001 0 0 1 1.25
ID_0002 0002 0 0 1 3.09
ID_0003 0003 0 0 1 -9
ID_0004 0004 0 0 1 2.69
```

This works because the last part `$1 in h?h[$1]:$6` means in pseudo code:

```
if $1 of current file=file1 belongs in keys of array h, 
  then 
      print h[$1] 
   else 
      print $6 of current file=file1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$3;next} $1 in a{$6=a[$1]} 1' file2 file1
ID_0001 0001 0 0 1 1.25
ID_0002 0002 0 0 1 3.09
ID_0003 0003 0 0 1 -9
ID_0004 0004 0 0 1 2.69
```